# Take in an object as a constructor

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have a program that has multiple interdependent classes. My guitar class sets the ranges that the vocal class needs to process. In order to pass the values from the guitar class to the vocal class I need to take a Guitar object as a constructor in the vocal class in order to get the values. How do I do this ?

I have the guitar object:
Guitar guitar = new Guitar ();

Comment: A constructor `public Vocal(Guitar g) {...}`? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Doesn't sound like `Vocals` should depend on `Guitar`. Instead, you should grab the range from `Guitar` then pass that to `Vocals`, or have the two share an object, which allows the `Guitar` to adjust the range and the `Vocals` to access the range.

Comment: I think so. In the ... I would pass in the parameters needed right?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a constructor,

```
public Vocal (Guitar g)
 {// do your stuff here with guitar object
 }
```

Then,

```
Vocal v = new Vocal (new Guitar());
```